# How to select even rows with list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I have the following layout with an unordered list:

https://codepen.io/barkins/pen/qjrpKJ

```
ul{
  max-width:1200px;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
li{
  width:12%;
  @media (max-width:720px){
    width:16%;
  }
  @media (max-width:480px){
    width:22%;
  }
}
```

I need to select only even rows, no matter the media query break points to add a border to only the 2nd row.

```
.second-row-items{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Is this possible to do with CSS and perhaps JavaScript (jQuery)?

---

I tried utilizing the following CSS rule to manually select the 2nd row, however it would best to have this be done automatically with JavaScript, somehow, and ideally select all the other even rows as well.

```
&:nth-child(n+9):nth-child(-n+16){
     border:1px solid red; 
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `(even)` and `(odd)` rules? https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: Yes, but I need to select rows, not elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use SCSS , you can use a loop to generate your :nth-child(xn+x) selectors :https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWpQbY?editors=1100

```
li {
  width: 12%;

  @for $i from 1 through 8 {
    &:nth-child(16n + #{$i}) {
      background: red;
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: 720px) {
    width: 16%;
    &:nth-child(1n) {
      background: none;/* reset previous rule */
    }

    @for $i from 1 through 6 {
      &:nth-child(12n + #{$i}) {
        background: red;
      }
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    width: 22%;
    &:nth-child(1n) {
      background: none;/* reset previous rule */
    }

    @for $i from 1 through 4 {
      &:nth-child(8n + #{$i}) {
        background: red;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The generated rules are not selecting the elements on a single row, as the OP has asked, but those in multiple of them. For example, `nth-child(16n + 1)` will select element 1, 17, 33... Also, multiple selectors with duplicated properties will be generated , when it can actually be done with a single selector (`li:nth-child(n+9):nth-child(-n+16)`) and no duplicated code. Totally overkill and suboptimal... 

Comment: @Danziger this answer is about looping css rules in SCSS. indeed the :nth-child(xn) is the basic selector to use . Sorry you dislike it :(

Comment: @GCyrillus Using `SCSS` is fine. What I'm saying is that the generated rules will not match the elements in the second row, as the OP has asked, but those in any odd row. Moreover, even is you change the selectors to match other elements, their properties (`background` only in this case), will be duplicated for each of them. To avoid that you should use `placeholder selectors (%)` and `%mixin`: 
`%second-row { background: pink; }` and `@for $i from 1 through 8 { &:nth-child(16n + #{$i}) { @extend %second-row; }}`

Comment: I was able to use the answer's example in my production code, and it worked perfectly in my use case. With this option, I have control over which rows are selected. Thanks @GCyrillus

Comment: @Danziger I think you should update your answer from your comment about your  scss approach. It is valuable and worth to be seen by anyone coming on this topic/question. Comments are not not read that much ;)

Answer (score 1):

That should do the job if you want to select only second row:

```
@media (max-width:480px)
{
  li:nth-child(5),
  li:nth-child(6),
  li:nth-child(7),
  li:nth-child(8)
  {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
@media (min-width:481px) and (max-width:720px)
{
  li:nth-child(7),
  li:nth-child(8),
  li:nth-child(9),
  li:nth-child(10),
  li:nth-child(11),
  li:nth-child(12)
  {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
@media (min-width:721px)
{
  li:nth-child(9),
  li:nth-child(10),
  li:nth-child(11),
  li:nth-child(12),
  li:nth-child(13),
  li:nth-child(14),
  li:nth-child(15),
  li:nth-child(16)
  {
    background-color: red;
  }  
}
```

And if you want all even rows, then use:

```
@media (max-width:480px)
{
  li:nth-child(8n-3),
  li:nth-child(8n-2),
  li:nth-child(8n-1),
  li:nth-child(8n)
  {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
@media (min-width:481px) and (max-width:720px)
{
  li:nth-child(12n-5),
  li:nth-child(12n-4),
  li:nth-child(12n-3),
  li:nth-child(12n-2),
  li:nth-child(12n-1),
  li:nth-child(12n)
  {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
@media (min-width:721px)
{
  li:nth-child(16n-7),
  li:nth-child(16n-6),
  li:nth-child(16n-5),
  li:nth-child(16n-4),
  li:nth-child(16n-3),
  li:nth-child(16n-2),
  li:nth-child(16n-1),
  li:nth-child(16n),
  {
    background-color: red;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Selecting elements in the second row only with CSS (breakpoint-specific)

It's not possible to select the elements in the second row regardless of the  media query breakpoints, so you will have to create selectors for the elements in that row for each breakpoint.

You can use two [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) to select a range of elements. For example:

```
li:nth-child(n + 7):nth-child(-n + 12)
```

Will select elements `7` to `12`, both included. That is, the second row if you have 6 columns.

```css
img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

ul {
  max-width:1200px;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

li {
  width:12%;
  font-size: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 721px) { 
  li:nth-child(n+9):nth-child(-n+16) {
    margin: 4px 0;
    padding: 16px 0;
    background: cyan;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
  li {
    width: 16%;
  }
  
  li:nth-child(n+7):nth-child(-n+12) {
    margin: 4px 0;
    padding: 16px 0;
    background: red;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  li {
    width: 22%;
  }
  
  li:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+8) {
    margin: 4px 0;
    padding: 16px 0;
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
</ul>
```

#### Selecting elements in the second row with JS (breakpoint-independent)

If you really need a generic solution that doesn't depend on specific code for each breakpoint, you can use `jQuery` or plain `JavaScript` to select the elements in the second row based on their position and add them a class.

Basically, you iterate them all and, each time the value of their [`.offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) changes, you just stepped into the next row.

Note you will have to listen to the [`resize` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) in order to update the selected elements, just in case a different breakpoint is active and the number of columns has changed:

```js
function styleSecondRow() {  
  let row = -1;
  let currentTop = -1;

  $('#grid > li').each(function() {
    let top = this.offsetTop;

    if (top > currentTop) {
      // We stepped into the next row:
      
      currentTop = top;
      
      ++row;
    }

    if (row === 1) {
      // Second row:
      
      this.classList.add('second-row');
    } else {
      // Remove .second-row from other rows:
      
      this.classList.remove('second-row');
    }
  });
}

// Update second row styling if window is resized:

$(window).resize(function() {
  styleSecondRow();
});

// Initialize second row styling for the firss time:

styleSecondRow();
```

```css
img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

ul {
  max-width:1200px;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

li {
  width:12%;
  font-size: 0;
}

.second-row {
  margin: 4px 0;
  padding: 16px 0;
  background: cyan;
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
  li {
    width: 16%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  li {
    width: 22%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="grid">
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Selecting elements in any even row using CSS

If you want to select elements in any even row, you need multiple selectors for each breakpoint, as `@JacobDesight` suggested. For example, if you had 8 columns, you would do this:

```
@media (...) {
    li {
        width: 12%;
    }

    li:nth-child(16n + 9),
    li:nth-child(16n + 10),
    li:nth-child(16n + 11),
    li:nth-child(16n + 12),
    li:nth-child(16n + 13),
    li:nth-child(16n + 14),
    li:nth-child(16n + 15),
    li:nth-child(16n + 16) {
        background: pink;

        ...
    }
}
```

Note you have multiple rules but just a single block of properties.

#### Selecting elements in any even row using SCSS, avoiding duplicated code

To do the same but using `SCSS`, if you forget about the media query for a second, you would normally use `@mixin`, `@include`, `@for` and `placeholder selector`:

```
// Placeholder selector that we will extend to avoid duplicating
// the properties for each generated nth-child selector:

%even-row { background: pink; }

// Mixin to avoid duplicating the @for block multiple times.
// It takes the number of columns as a parameter:

@mixin even-rows-mixin($columns) {
    @for $i from 1 through $columns {
        &:nth-child(#{2 * $columns}n + #{$i + $columns}) {
            @extend %even-row;
        }
    }
}

li {
    @include even-rows-mixin(8);
    width: 12%;
}
```

This will generate the following code:

```
li:nth-child(16n + 9),
li:nth-child(16n + 10),
li:nth-child(16n + 11),
li:nth-child(16n + 12),
li:nth-child(16n + 13),
li:nth-child(16n + 14),
li:nth-child(16n + 15),
li:nth-child(16n + 16) {
    background: pink;
}

li {
    width: 12%;
}
```

However, you can't use `@extend` inside media queries.

If you remove the `@extend`, you will end up with something similar to what `@GCyrillus` suggested. You can wrap that in a `mixin` to avoid duplicating the `@for` block in each media query, but that will still generate duplicated code. The mixin will look like this:

```
@mixin even-rows-mixin($columns) {
    @for $i from 1 through $columns {
        &:nth-child(#{2 * $columns}n + #{$i + $columns}) {
            background: pink;
        }
    }
}
```

It will generate `$columns` selectors and blocks of duplicated properties (only `background` in this example), which will make your stylesheet grow fast if you use this `mixin` too much or if you add more properties to it.

**EDIT:** I suspected this could be done using interpolation, but was not sure about it, so I opened another question and someone came to the rescue: [SCSS @extend inside media query alternatives to avoid duplicate properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640846/scss-extend-inside-media-query-alternatives-to-avoid-duplicate-properties)

Basically, you should build a selector variable in the mixin and use interpolation to create a rule with a fixed set of properties, or `@content` if you prefer to set them dynamically:

```
@mixin even-rows-mixin($columns, $rule) {
    $selector : '';

    @for $i from 1 through $columns {
        $selector:  $selector + $rule + '('+ #{2 * $columns}n  + ' + ' + #{$i + $columns} + '),';
    }  

    #{$selector} {
        @content; // Or just add your properties here.
    }
}

...

@media(...) {

    ...

    @include even-rows-mixin(8, 'li:nth-child') {
        background: pink; 
    };

    ...

}
```

Note this code does not compile in CodePen, but it does when using `node-sass` or this other online compiler: http://beautifytools.com/scss-compiler.php

Answer (score -1):

Okay the key is to know how many images will be in each row on each breakpoint.

If at large screen, you have 6 items in a row, then you want 7-12 underlined (the second row), but not 13-18, but 19-24, etc. For medium, it may be 4. Small 2, Extra small, 1 (just an example).

You could use Javascript to select those rows, and add your class `.second-row-items` to them.

You might have to take the width of the container and divide it by the width of the images to find out how many items can fit in a row (`n`), and then take the total number of items and divide that by the number of items that fit in a row to get the number of rows. Then you could write a function that selects every `nth` child (to get get the row) and `nth` siblings (to get the entire row) to add your class.

Comment: i think OP is asking for the row not for each list item

Comment: Ahh good point. I didn't look at the codepen, just went off even.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to select even li then go with :nth-child{even}

In your case, code would be

```
ul li:nth-child(even){ border: 1px solid black;}
```