# SCSS @extend inside media query alternatives to avoid duplicate properties

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, mixins, extend

In `SCSS`, you can use `@mixin` and `@extend` to reuse code. For example:

```
%even-row { background: pink; }

@mixin even-rows-mixin($columns) {
    @for $i from 1 through $columns {
        &:nth-child(#{2 * $columns}n + #{$i + $columns}) {
            @extend %even-row;
        }
    }
}

li {
    @include even-rows-mixin(8);
    width: 12%;
}
```

Will generate:

```
li:nth-child(16n + 9),
li:nth-child(16n + 10),
li:nth-child(16n + 11),
li:nth-child(16n + 12),
li:nth-child(16n + 13),
li:nth-child(16n + 14),
li:nth-child(16n + 15),
li:nth-child(16n + 16) {
    background: pink;
}

li {
    width: 12%;
}
```

However, I'd like to use that `mixin` inside a media query, which is not possible:

```
@media (max-width: X) {
    li {
        @include even-rows-mixin(8);
        width: 12%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: Y) {
    li {
        @include even-rows-mixin(4);
        width: 16%;
    }
}
```

This will throw an error:

```
You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media. You may only 
@extend selectors within the same directive. From "@extend %even-row"
on line N.
```

I could just remove `@extend` and inline the properties in the `mixin`:

```
@mixin even-rows-mixin($columns) {
    @for $i from 1 through $columns {
        &:nth-child(#{2 * $columns}n + #{$i + $columns}) {
            background: pink;
        }
    }
}
```

But that will generate duplicated code:

```
@nth-child(16n + 9)  { background: pink; }
@nth-child(16n + 10) { background: pink; }

...

@nth-child(16n + 16) { background: pink; }
```

I wonder if there's a better way to write this code without generating duplicated properties or having to write all the possible selectors manually, maybe using interpolation or some other feature I'm not aware of.

This question came to me after answering this other question: [How to select even rows with list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636845/how-to-select-even-rows-with-list-items/44637284#44637284), just as a reference if you want to take a look to the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a selector variable with the entire selector group.

```
@mixin even-rows-mixin($columns, $rule) {
   $selector : '';
    @for $i from 1 through $columns {
      $selector:  $selector + $rule + '('+ #{2 * $columns}n  + "+" + #{$i + $columns} + ') ,';
    }  
  #{$selector} {
    @content;
  }
}

li {
    width: 12%;
}
@include even-rows-mixin(8, 'li:nth-child') {
 background-color: pink; 
};
```

Note: For some reason its not working in codepen editor. But it's working with node-sass

Answer (score 0):

Could you place the `%even-row` inside the mixin definition? I haven't tried, though, it might throw an error.

Comment: Here's an idea but I find it a bit hacky: create a variable in the scope of each media query, like ```$mixin-iteration: 0;``` and every time you call your mixin, check if the variable's value is zero and add the ```%even-row```, and increment the variable's value. That way it'll only be called once per media query… I suppose?

Comment: That won't work anyway, as you are still using `@extend` inside the media query. Even if it did, if you just call that for the first iteration, all selectors but the first one will be missing. Take a look at @karthick answer, that's exactly what I meant by _using interpolation_.

Comment: That is indeed a decent way of doing it, I'm glad someone could help you out. I should have tried testing my suggestions before posting them!